# Why didn't Adam kill himself?

Tags: forever

Why, in the finale forever, did Adam not kill himself?

He knows that he is immortal, and that Henry is killing him.  He walks up to the platforms, and tries to kill himself with a train; why didn't he use the dagger that Henry threw on the floor?

Comment: We can only assume he didn't really want to die; unfortunately we'll probably never know :(